Understanding a proof that a set equals to its closure implies the set is closed.
This proof is presented in V.A. Zorich Mathematical Analysis I p.415. I have done some research on the internet but it seems like both the definitions and the proof used in this book are unique.
The proposition that we are proving is:

($F$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$)$\iff$($F$=$\bar{F}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m)$.

The definitions used are:

A set $G\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if for every point $x\in G$ there is a ball $B(x;\delta)$ such that $B(x;\delta)\subset G$.


The set $F\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if its complement $G=\mathbb{R}^m\backslash F$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$.


A point $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is a limit point of the set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ if for any neighborhood $O(a)$ of $a$ the intersection $E\cap O(a)$ is an infinite set.

And $\bar{E}=E\cup E’$, where $E’$ is the set of all limit points of $E$.
As the proof for necessity is clear for me, I will only copy the part proving the sufficiency here:

Let $F=\bar{F}$. We shall verify that the set $G=\mathbb{R}^m\backslash\bar{F}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. If $x\in G$, then $x\notin F$, and therefore $x$ is not a limit point of $F$. Hence there is a neighborhood of $x$ containing only a finite number of points $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ of $F$. Since $x\notin F$, one can construct, for example, balls about $x$, $O_1(x),\cdots,O_n(x)$ such that $x_i\notin O_i(x)$. Then $O(x)=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^nO_i(x)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ containing no points of $F$ at all, that is $O(c)\subset\mathbb{R}^m\backslash F$ and hence the set $\mathbb{R}^m\backslash F=\mathbb{R}^m\backslash\bar{F}$ is open. Therefore $F$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

The bold texts are where I found I couldn’t understand. I find the common definition of a limit point of a set is simply the intersection of any neighborhoods of the point and the set is non-empty, not necessarily infinite. Then, the bold texts will imply the equivalent of these two definitions, but I can’t see how it makes sense.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

Since $x\not\in F$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n\in F$, we know that $x\neq x_i$ for all $i$. This means that $d(x,x_i)>0$ where $d$ is the distance function (in this case the Euclidean distance). We can take $O_i(x)$ to be the ball centered at $x$ with radius $d(x,x_i)$, then $x_i\not\in O_i(x)$.
I hope this helps, let me know if there are more steps you don't understand.
As for the definition of limit point, there are two versions in use. Some people call $\overline{E}$ the limit points, that is the closure. Others call only $E'$ the limit points. The difference $\overline{E}\backslash E'$ are the so called isolated points. A point is isolated if there is a neighborhood which only contains that point. $E'$ excludes these isolated points. If a point $x$ is in the closure but isn't isolated, we can approach the point arbitrarily close without reaching it. Taking a sequence of increasingly close approximations provides an infinite number of points in any neighborhood of $x$.

You have made yourself very clear, thanks a lot. I have forgot that we are working in a metric space.
